# Excel remove @domain.com from username

Tags: excel

I have a list of 400 email addresses in an Excel spreadsheet that I need to truncate so I will be able to delete them from our email system. However, the program requires that I only use the user name and remove the domain name. Currently in the spreadsheet, the email addresses are listed as

> username@subdomain.domain.com.

The result I need would appear with just the user anme and removing the @subdomain.domain.com portion.

I tried the following formula from another thread on Stack Overflow:

> > =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1))

This resulted in a circular reference error in the program that I was unable to fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Circular reference? That formula is referencing cell A1.  It could only result in a circular reference if the cell you're typing the formula into is also cell A1.  Cell A1 should contain the email address, in which case you should put the formula in a blank cell, like B1 (if column B is blank).  Then copy down.  You can either hide the original column so that only the formula results are displayed, or you can copy the formula column -> right-click -> paste special -> Values

Comment: @tigeravatar is right, read up on [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/allow-or-correct-a-circular-reference-HP005200285.aspx) to learn about circular references. Feel free to check out my answer below to understand how to tackle the answer

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `username@subdomain.domain.com` is in cell A1, the following formula in another cell will get the first part before the `@`

`=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",A1)-1)`

If you use table formulas, you can come up with a nice table like this

```
Email                             Usernames   Domains

username@subdomain.domain.com     username    subdomain.domain.com
username2@subdomain2.domain.com   username2   subdomain2.domain.com
```

Then your formula in the `Usernames` field will be this

`=LEFT([@Email],FIND("@",[@Email])-1)`

And your formula in the `Domains` field will be

`=RIGHT([@Email],LEN([@Email])-FIND("@",[@Email]))`

Comment: @user3731293 just got a notification for an upvote on this answer, if you don't mind, feel free to accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apply Text to Columns on a copy with `@` as the delimiter and delete the 'spare' column/s.